# How to add another table when comparing tables using criteria?

Tags: hibernate, subquery, criteria

I am comparing two tables using hibernate criteria based on second table id value, but i need second table values in a single list. Here is my code

```
DetachedCriteria subquery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(
                    Users.class).setProjection(
                    Projections.property("empCd"));
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Employee.class);
criteria.add(Property.forName(YRLBatchConstants.EMP_CODE)
                    .in(subquery));
lstEmpMaster = criteria.list();
```

I am comparing User and Employee field employee code and generating some datas in list but i get only Employee objects but i require some more fields from the User table also.

Can anyone help me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Hibernate Criteria doesn't support [theta-style joins](http://learningviacode.blogspot.ro/2012/10/theta-style-joins.html). So you can use an HQL query instead:

```
List<Object[]> properties = session.createQuery(
    "select e.name, u.name 
    from Employee e, Users u
    where e.empCd = u.empCd")
.list();
```